# Is there any functon to do a summation over Matrix on Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

When I do a summation over a matrix:

```
import sympy
i = sy.symbols('i')
A=Matrix([1,i,3,3*i])
summation(A[i],(i,0,3))
```

That Results:

```
IndexError: Invalid index a[i]
```

I know I can solve this problem with a loop.

Isn't there any function to sum that supports sympy matrix?

Comment: Is the use of `i` as `a[i]` index, and as a variable with in `A` intentional?  meaningful?  Do you want `1 + i + 3 + 3i => 4 + 4i` or `1 + 1 + 3+ 3*3 => 13`?

Answer (score 0):

You can sum over the vector A a by multiplication with a vector of ones of respective shape.

`A.T * ones(A.shape[0], 1)`